# What are the most useful (custom) code snippets for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

What are the best code snippets for C#? (using visual studio)  VB has a lot that are pre-defined, but there are only a handful for C#.  Do you have any really useful ones for C#?

Anyone want to post a good custom one you created yourself?

[Anyone?... Bueller?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferris_Bueller)

Comment: You're really going to have to be more specific...

Are you looking for websites that contain web snippets and tutorials? Code snippets themselves on a particular topic? This is a very, very general question.

Comment: Have you even used any code snippets?
There is no "best" code snippets.  There are snippets that are more "useful" than others, but no "best" snippets.  I wish i can edit the title...

Comment: Snippets work well for situation and save typing.  For example I have created custom snippets because I am replacing some old code in files, and I can't use copy replace, so I can highlight the old code, and then use my snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft have released a whole bunch of C# snippets that bring it up to parity with the ones for Visual Basic. You can download them here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx

Comment: cool, thanks.  I didn't see these...

Answer (score 8):

My absolute favorite is `cw`.

Answer (score 5):

There's plenty of code snippets within Visual Studio for basic programming structure but I wouldn't necessarily rate one higher than another.

I would definitely say the best ones are the custom snippets you define yourself to accomplish more specific tasks that you may find yourself using on a regular basis. Definitely a big time saver.

A fairly basic intro to creating custom snippets can be found at http://www.15seconds.com/issue/080724.htm to help with this.

Answer (score 2):

These are the ones I use daily.

- prop
- try
- if
- else
- for
- foreach
- mbox - Message box stub
- The ability to role your own.  I have one for Property that are saved in the view state, methods a custom class example.

Answer (score 2):

I had a few on my old blog:

- [testmethod Code Snippet](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2008/12/01/testmethod-code-snippet.aspx)
- [onevent Code Snippet](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2006/03/17/oneventCodeSnippet.aspx)
- [cleantestresults Code Snippet](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2007/06/25/cleantestresultsXMLSnippet.aspx)
- [astype Code Snippet](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2006/03/20/astypeCodeSnippet.aspx)

I also have an `argnull` code snippet that inserts a Guard Clause that checks an argument for null and throws an ArgumentNullException, but I haven't gotten around to post that yet.

Answer (score 1):

prop and exception are my favorites.

Answer (score 1):

I just started a blog, where I document short solutions in C# (code snippets) that I came up with and might prove useful to other coders.

http://thorstenlorenz.blogspot.com/

So far I have mostly blogged about extension methods and generics.

So have a look and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update an older thread... here's a link for Visual Studio 2008 C# code snippet download.

[VS 2008 C# Code Snippet Download](http://www.codeplex.com/snippetlibcsharp)